# What is the name of a set of up to k ordered samples with replacement?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, terminology

Is there a name for this set? Suppose I have a set $S$, and I take up to $k$ samples from $S$ with replacement. What is the name of the set of possible results? The order of the samples matters, and $k$ can be any whole number.

e.g. If $S = \{a,b\}$ and $k=3$, the set whose name I am trying to find is $\{(a), (b), (a,a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b), (a,a,a), (a,a,b), (a,b,a), (a,b,b), (b,a,a), (b,a,b), (b,b,a), (b,b,b)\}$. It might also include the empty tuple $()$ - I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks like $S + S^2 + S^3$, but I don't know a name for that.

Comment: If you wrote $S^{\leq3}$, people would probably understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean the general case, not for a specific $k$. $\cup_{i=0}^kS^i$ is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are $(a,a), (b,b) $ intentionally missed?

Comment: @user No, that's a typo